# How to stream iTunes content to Chromecast

Tags: itunes, chromecast

Is it possible to stream my iTunes moves and TV series to my Chromecast?

I've found some solutions on Google but I'd like to avoid tricky transcoding processes.

What's the easiest solution?

Comment: You can open spotify web and play music. Video, not sure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have actually downloaded the file, simply drag it into the Chrome browser - it will play your file locally and you can stream it from there.  I don't know of any solution built into iTunes that would allow you to stream directly to the Chromecast.  I do this with iTunes U lectures all the time.

Comment: Are your sure this will work with DRM protected content? I thought only iTunes could play such content.